# Automatically show the result to a text when ever a numeric value is being typed

Tags: c#, .net, ascii, keyboard-events

I have three text boxes the first one price textbox has a constant value while I have to input a value to the second one, the third one then shows the result of multiplying those two values 
[textboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X85Kr.png)

So what I wanna do here is whenever I type a value in the quantity text box for example, 10 the subtotal automatically shows the result, and when I delete it, it will turn back to zero

Here's my code so far which I made an event KeyDown

```
 private void txtQuantity_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            KeysConverter kc = new KeysConverter();
            string keyChar = kc.ConvertToString(e.KeyCode);
            double quantity = Convert.ToDouble(keyChar);
            double price = Convert.ToDouble(txtPrice.Text);
            double subtotal = quantity * price;
            txtSubtotal.Text = subtotal.toString();
        }
```

this is working but when I type in another number next to the first one, it gets the value of the second one instead of the value of the whole, and when I type backspace it gets an error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMZH3.png)

Comment: Instead of reading just the keycode (which will return the `0` on the second event when you type in `10`), read the entire value of the textbox.  Also, you don't validate that any of the input is in fact a number.

Comment: so how do I do it with an event?

Comment: `var quantity = (sender as TextBox).Text;` -- you'll need to do some validation and the conversion from string to double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead for _KeyDown event you can try with _TextChanged to accomplish the target: Let the controls be `txtQty`,`txtPrice` and `txtTotal` where price is disabled and holds the constant value.

```
    private void txtQty_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double price, qty, total;
        double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price);
        if (!double.TryParse(txtQty.Text, out qty))
        {
            txtTotal.Text = "0.00";
            txtQty.BackColor = Color.Red; //indicates wrong input
        }
        else
        {               
            total = price * qty;
            txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("#0.00");
        }
    }
```

Note : In the above snippet i have given an additional feature that; background color of the `txtQty` becomes `red` if the user enter a wrong input;

Comment: I have another question, how can I format the total textbox where it show 2 decimal values as a result?

Comment: @carlplusplus: use `total.ToString("#0.00");` i have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

un-lucky has the best answer.

However, a take on how I'd do it using your existing event handler:

```
var quantityInput = sender as TextBox;
double quantity = 0;
double price = 0;
double.TryParse(txtPrice.Text, out price);

if (quantityInput != null)
{
    double.TryParse(quantityInput.Text.Trim(), out quantity);
}

txtSubtotal.Text = quantity * price;
```